# Java Double-Ended Queue implementation: Unable to find logic error in method addLast()

Tags: java, linked-list, deque

My code:

**NOTE**: Functions like readInt() and readString() are part of Princeton University's algs4.jar package.

```js
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;

public class Deque < Item > implements Iterable < Item > {

  private Node < Item > front;
  private Node < Item > back;
  private int numberOfItems;

  private class Node < Item > {
    Item item;
    Node < Item > next;
    Node < Item > prev;
  }

  public Deque() {
    front = null;
    back = null;
    numberOfItems = 0;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (numberOfItems == 0);
  }

  public int size() {
    return numberOfItems;
  }

  public void addFirst(Item item) {
    if (item == null) {
      // When a null element is entered
      throw new java.lang.NullPointerException("Item cannot be null");
    }
    Node < Item > newnode = new Node < Item > ();
    newnode.item = item;
    if (numberOfItems == 0) {
      // When there are no elements
      front = newnode;
      back = newnode;
    } else {
      // When there are >=1 elements
      newnode.prev = front;
      newnode.next = null;
      front.next = newnode;
      front = newnode;

    }
    numberOfItems++;
  }

  public void addLast(Item item) {
    if (item == null) {
      // When a null element is entered
      throw new java.lang.NullPointerException("Item cannot be null");
    }
    Node < Item > newnode = new Node < Item > ();
    newnode.item = item;
    if (numberOfItems == 0) {
      // When there are no elements
      front = newnode;
      back = newnode;
    } else {
      // When there are >=1 elements
      newnode.next = back;
      newnode.prev = null;
      back.prev = newnode;
      back = newnode;
    }
    numberOfItems++;
  }

  public Item removeFirst() {
    if (numberOfItems == 0) {
      // When the deque is empty
      throw new NoSuchElementException("No item to remove");
    }
    Item oldfirst = front.item;
    if (numberOfItems == 1) {
      front = null;
      back = null;
    } else {
      front = front.prev;
    }
    numberOfItems--;
    return oldfirst;
  }

  public Item removeLast() {
    if (numberOfItems == 0) {
      // When deque is empty
      throw new NoSuchElementException("No item to remove");
    }
    Item oldlast = back.item;
    if (numberOfItems == 1) {
      front = null;
      back = null;
    } else {
      back = back.next;
    }
    numberOfItems--;
    return oldlast;
  }

  public Iterator < Item > iterator() {
    return new ListIterator();
  }

  private class ListIterator implements Iterator < Item > {
    private Node < Item > current = front;

    public boolean hasNext() {
      return (current != null);
    }

    public void remove() {
      throw UnsupportedOperationException("remove is unsupported");
    }

    public Item next() {
      Item item = current.item;
      current = current.prev;
      return item;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Deque < String > deq = new Deque();
    String word;
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
      String cmd = StdIn.readString();
      if (cmd.equals("af")) {
        word = StdIn.readString();
        deq.addFirst(word);
      } else if (cmd.equals("al")) {
        word = StdIn.readString();
        deq.addFirst(word);
      } else if (cmd.equals("rf")) {
        deq.removeFirst();
      } else if (cmd.equals("rl")) {
        deq.removeLast();
      } else if (cmd.equals("noi")) {
        StdOut.println(deq.size());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm implementing the Deque as a collection of linked nodes. Each node has three characteristics- the content, a link to the next item and  a link to the previous item. The class variables front and back are pointers for the first and the last element respectively.

When I was ran the program with my test client, I discovered that the method addLast(Item) here, inserts the item in the front instead of the rear.

Why is this happening? What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: My guess is that you swapped the roles of the `front` and `back` nodes.  You should check your logic throughout, as similar problems may be present in all your methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your `addLast` code

```
  public void addLast(Item item) {
    if (item == null) {
      // When a null element is entered
      throw new java.lang.NullPointerException("Item cannot be null");
    }
    Node < Item > newnode = new Node < Item > ();
    newnode.item = item;
    if (numberOfItems == 0) {
      // When there are no elements
      front = newnode;
      back = newnode;
    } else {
      // When there are >=1 elements
      newnode.next = back;
      newnode.prev = null;
      back.prev = newnode;
      back = newnode;
    }
    numberOfItems++;
  }
```

Note that when there's one node, the `front` and the `back` point to the same node. Then when you add the second node to the back, you assign `back.prev` to `newnode`, which is wrong. It should have been:

```
back.next = newnode;
newnode.prev = back;
back = newnode;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code

```
 public void addLast(Item item) {
    if (item == null) {
      // When a null element is entered
      throw new java.lang.NullPointerException("Item cannot be null");
    }
    Node < Item > newnode = new Node < Item > ();
    newnode.item = item;
    if (numberOfItems == 0) {
      // When there are no elements
      front = newnode;
      back = newnode;
    } else {
      // When there are >=1 elements
      //**Here is the issue**
      newnode.next = back;
      newnode.prev = null;
      back.prev = newnode;
      back = newnode;
    }
    numberOfItems++;
  }
```

Instead of

```
 newnode.next = back;
 newnode.prev = null;
 back.prev = newnode;
 back = newnode;
```

It should be

```
back.next = newnode;
newnode.prev=back;
newnode.next = null;
back = newnode
```

Hope this helps